# Socketconnection via wifi

Tags: c++, sockets, wifi, boost-asio

I want to connect my mobile phone via wifi with my computer. 
I tested it with the tool "SocketTest" and the Android app "TCP Client". There it works great.
But if I try the following Code (as a test), the "TCP Client"-App can't connect.

```
int main() {
    boost::asio::io_context io_context;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_context, boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), 25100));
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket sock(io_context);
    acceptor.accept(sock);

    std::cout << "New Connection!" << std::endl;
}
```

or

```
int main() {
    boost::asio::io_context io_context;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_context, boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("192.168.178.35"), 25100));
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket sock(io_context);
    acceptor.accept(sock);

    std::cout << "New Connection!" << std::endl;
}
```

I can connect to the socket from my to pc to my pc. So the socket is open. But I can't connect from smartphone.

Comment: "I can connect to the socket from my to pc to my pc." The same PC or a different PC on a LAN? Have you verified there isn't a firewall meddling with things?

Comment: The same PC. I approved the port in the Firewall. All conditions are the same like the test with the "SocketTest"-Software.

Comment: Can you also post the code you are using to connect from your smartphone?

Comment: There is no code^^. I use an Android App named "TCP Client".

Comment: I have now tried 3 other apps. All work with "SocketTest"-Tool. But none of them with my code.

Comment: If it only works locally, I would think you are binding to loopback.

Comment: It works locally. And if I copy this to a root Server, I can connect from my pc to the server.